# $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function s.t. $f(2x,y^2)=f(x,y)\forall(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Prove $\nabla f(1,1)=2\nabla f(2,1)$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

This is the first time I have encountered a question like this. I don't even know where to start to solve this. I've been stuck doing this for at least 30 minutes, and I have gone nowhere. Please help.

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that $f(2x,y^2)=f(x,y)$ for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Show that $\nabla f(1,1)=2\nabla f(2,1)$.

Comment: Have you bothered to compute the gradient?

Comment: Let $g(x, y) = f(2x, y^2)$ and write $\nabla g$ in terms of $f$ using the chain rule. Then note that $g=f$, so $\nabla g = \nabla f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(x,y)=f(2x,y^2)$, then using the chain rule we get that

$$\partial_1f(x,y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigl(f(2x,y^2)\bigr)=2\partial_1f(2x,y^2),$$
$$\partial_2f(x,y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigl(f(2x,y^2)\bigr)=2y\partial_2f(2x,y^2).$$

In particular then

$$\partial_1f(1,1)=2\partial_1f(2,1),$$
$$\partial_2f(1,1)=2\partial_2f(2,1),$$

i.e.

$$\nabla f(1,1)=2\nabla f(2,1).$$

Comment: Umm i dont understand  why you just added the coefficient 2 in the right side ?

Comment: @user20194358 it's the inner derivative from differentiating $2x$ with respect to $x$. Remember the chain rule

Comment: @user20194358 I added an additional step to the computation to perhaps make it a bit clearer

Comment: yes now it makes sense thank you